# How Can I post Data(Json object) from Angular 2 to Web api?

Tags: angular

Angular Code is ::

> app.component.ts

---

**Json data**

```
    this.objsearch=[{ "Key": "FirstName", "value": this.firstName },
        { "Key": "MiddleName", "value": this.middleName },
        { "Key": "fatherName ", "value": this.fatherName },
        { "Key": "motherName", "value": this.motherName },
        { "Key": "_UId", "value": this._UId },
        { "Key": "Country", "value": this.ddlcountry },
        { "Key": "State", "value": this.ddlState },
        { "Key": "City", "value": this.ddlCity },
        ]
```

**Method to call service.ts**

```
      this.ServiceObject.saveData(Json.Strigify(this.objsearch)).subscribe(response => (this._param) = response);
```

> **Service.ts**

```
public_saveDataURL="http://localhost:53915/api/ComapnyAndProduct/DeleteItem";
```

**Method::**

```
saveData(objSearch: any) 
{
    return this._http.post(this._saveDataURL,objSearch)
   .map((response: Response) => response.json()); 
}
```

> **Web Api Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteItem([FromUri]Mregistration objSearch)
{
return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSON.strigify(this.objsearch)` at the `saveData`.

```
this.ServiceObject.saveData(this.objsearch).subscribe(response => (this._param) = response);
```

Also you need to get data from the body not from the url.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteItem([FromBody]Mregistration objSearch)
{
   return Ok();
}
```

And your object must have a structure like this

```
this.objsearch = {
   firstName: this.firstName,
   middleName: this.middleName,
   fatherName: this.fatherName,
   motherName: this.matherName,
   _Uid: this._Uid,
   country: this.ddlcountry,
   state: this.ddlState,
   city: this.ddlCity
}
```

Comment: Is there any way so i can post json data ?

Comment: It will get JSON. Your properties names must match to your `Mregistration` type properties

Comment: public string  FirstName { get; set; }

Comment: The problem is that you pass properties with `key` and `value` pairs. but your object contains the values of key as a property. You need to constructor an object with those names and pass it. I have updated answer

Comment: If I have post in key value pair then what should i do

Comment: You can get data as `Dictionary<string, hereYourTypeOfProperties>`

Comment: Suren, one more thing if i will not use model class ,instead of model class   if i use     
                public IHttpActionResult DeleteItem ([fromUri] string objSearch)          then can i receive data in form of string

Comment: Suren,I already trying to upvote ,but due to low reputation I m not able to upvote,Sorry